# How to force user to enter correct value, otherwise not let user to go to other fields or activity?

Tags: android

How to force user to enter correct value in EditView, otherwise not let user to go to other fields or activity?

I aware of setError() method to show the invalid data, but I also need user to enter the right info before they leave the current field.

Comment: You could disable all other fields I guess

Comment: i think you looking for **OnTextChangedListener()**

Comment: To Tim. Yea, straight forward solution I guess. How about to prevent user from leave this current activity? I am thinking inject code before all startActivity() method in my application to prevent user leave the current activity, this is my last resort if no other better solution.

Comment: To ntc. I couldn't find setOnTextChangedListener() from EditView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way to do it, the easiest way is to check the value at a event handler which trigger before the focus left the current field.